# Oracle + FireDac return empty strings

Tags: delphi, oracle11g, delphi-xe5, string, firedac

All my oracle varchar2 data returns empty(EmptyStr) using an firedac connection + firedacQuery.  I tryed an ADO connection on same database and all strings appear normally.
Can anyone explain? Im using delphi XE5 + oracle 11g, database charset is WE8ISO8859P15.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to resolve my problem by updating the oci driver.